# IWebBrowser2 HTTP response headers

Tags: .net, http-headers, iwebbrowser2

I have the same question that [Dragos asked here](http://www.ms-news.net/f3731/iwebbrowser2-http-response-headers-1749703.html)

"...Hi! I'm developing an application which hosts an web browser control.
I'm getting access to it through IWebBrowser2 interface. Is there any
way to have access programatically to the responses header..."

The solution (from 2003) seems to be using an passthrough Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol (APP) handlers. The solution presented [here](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.inetsdk.programming.mshtml_hosting/browse_frm/thread/8e881e342e0d5f35/7013a517c207d543) was written in C++/ATL so I was wondering if there is an c# version of this?

Note that I'm already able to get the cookie values from IWebBrowser2 (and WatiN), the issue is getting the raw headers values

Comment: The answer on this article a bit of insight into this :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758426/is-it-possible-to-see-what-the-response-headers-were-after-a-page-load-using-wat

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen a pure-C# implementation of an APP ever. CodeProject has had the [the most complete C# webbrowser wrapper control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx) project article for a long time. It should allow you to access the response headers information via C#, however the APP is not in C#.