# Is it possible to see what the response headers were after a page load using Watin

Tags: testing, watin

Part of our testing is to check that a page is being returned in the correct format (specifically gzip)

Does WATIN expose the HTTP response headers so they can be inspected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, WatiN doesn't expose the HTTP response headers neither Internet Explorer. It's not possible to get them using InternetExplorer interface or any of it's events.

Comment: Maybe if you integrate an HTTP traffic sniffer while WatiN is running, you might be able to parse the received headers separately but within your automation using code. But that's beyond my scope of expertise to implement.